# Java regex of string

Tags: java, regex, parsing, mapreduce

I want to parse strings to get fields from them. The format of the string (which come from a dataset) is as so (the -> represents a tab, and the * represents a space):

```
Date(yyyymmdd)->Date(yyyymmdd)->*City,*State*-->Description
```

I am only interested in the 1st date and the State. I tried regex like this:

```
String txt="19951010    19951011     Red City, WI                 Description";

    String re1="(\\d+)";    // Integer Number 1
    String re2=".*?";   // Non-greedy match on filler
    String re3="(?:[a-z][a-z]+)";   // Uninteresting: word
    String re4=".*?";   // Non-greedy match on filler
    String re5="(?:[a-z][a-z]+)";   // Uninteresting: word
    String re6=".*?";   // Non-greedy match on filler
    String re7="((?:[a-z][a-z]+))"; // Word 1

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(re1+re2+re3+re4+re5+re6+re7,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(txt);
    if (m.find())
    {
        String int1=m.group(1);
        String word1=m.group(2);
        System.out.print("("+int1.toString()+")"+"("+word1.toString()+")"+"\n");
    }
```

It works fine id the city has two words (Red City) then the State is extracted properly, but if the City only has one word it does not work. I can't figure it out, I don't need to use regex and am open to any other suggestions. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem:**

Your problem is that each component of your current regex essentially matches a number or [a-z] word, separated by anything that isn't [a-z], which includes commas. So your parts for a two word city are:

```
Input: 
  19951010 19951011 Red City, WI Description

Your components:
  String re1="(\\d+)";    // Integer Number 1
  String re2=".*?";   // Non-greedy match on filler
  String re3="(?:[a-z][a-z]+)";   // Uninteresting: word
  String re4=".*?";   // Non-greedy match on filler
  String re5="(?:[a-z][a-z]+)";   // Uninteresting: word
  String re6=".*?";   // Non-greedy match on filler
  String re7="((?:[a-z][a-z]+))"; // Word 1

What they match:
  re1: "19951010"
  re2: " 19951011 "
  re3: "Red" (stops at non-letter, e.g. whitespace)
  re4: " "
  re5: "City" (stops at non-letter, e.g. the comma)
  re6: ", " (stops at word character)
  re7: "WI"
```

But with a one-word city:

```
Input: 
  19951010 19951011 Pittsburgh, PA Description

What they match:
  re1: "19951010"
  re2: " 19951011 "
  re3: "Pittsburgh" (stops at non-letter, e.g. the comma)
  re4: ","
  re5: "PA" (stops at non-letter, e.g. whitespace)
  re6: " " (stops at word character)
  re7: "Description" (but you want this to be the state)
```

---

**Solution:**

You should do two things. First, simplify your regex a bit; you are going kind of crazy specifying greedy vs. reluctant, etc. Just use greedy patterns. Second, think about the simplest way to express your rules.

Your rules really are:

- Date
- A bunch of characters that aren't a comma (including second date and city name).
- A comma.
- State (one word).

So build a regex that sticks to that. You can, as you are doing now, take a shortcut by skipping the second number, but note that you do lose support for cities that start with numbers (which probably won't happen). Also you don't care about the state. So, e.g.:

```
String re1 = "(\\d+)";   // match first number
String re2 = "[^,]*";    // skip everything thats not a comma
String re3 = ",";        // skip the comma
String re4 = "[\\s]*";   // skip whitespace
String re5 = "([a-z]+)"; // match letters (state)

String regex = re1 + re2 + re3 + re4 + re5;
```

There are other options as well, but I personally find regular expressions to be very straightforward for things like this. You could use various combinations of `split()`, as other posters have detailed. You could directly look for commas and whitespace with `indexOf()` and pull out substrings. You could even convince a `Scanner` or perhaps a `StringTokenizer` or `StreamTokenizer` to work for you. However, regular expressions exist to solve problems like this and are a good tool for the job.

Here is an example with `StringTokenizer`:

```
StringTokenizer t = new StringTokenizer(txt, " \t");
String date = t.nextToken();
t.nextToken(); // skip second date
t.nextToken(","); // change delimiter to comma and skip city
t.nextToken(" \t"); // back to whitespace and skip comma
String state = t.nextToken();
```

Still, I feel a regex expresses the rules more cleanly.

By the way, for future debugging, sometimes it helps to just print out all of the capture groups, this can give you insight into what is matching what. A good technique is to put *every* component of your regex in a capture group temporarily, then print them all out.

Answer (score 0):

no need to be so complex with this. you can split on whitespace!

```
//s is your string
String[] first = s.split("\\s*,\\s*")
String[] firstHalf = first[0].split("\\s+")
String[] secondHalf = first[1].split("\\s+")
String date = firstHalf[0]
String state = secondHalf[0]
```

now you have youre `date` and your `state`! do with them what you want.

Comment: This has the same issue that the OP's regex does, where it fails if the city was not two words. What you would want to do is split the string at the comma, then split each of those strings at whitespace, then take the first token in each of those.

Comment: fair enough. I was basing this simply on the placements of the "*"s and "->"s in the question

Comment: Now this should work fine! Thank you for pointing this out, I should have read the question more carefully!